# How can I get function and property proposals after the dot of a variant in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, object, ms-word, delphi-xe7, variant

I'm just about to learn connecting MsWord with Delphi. The small...very small...program I wrote is working but I do not get the proposals after the dot of an object.

My code (I copied everything which I thought could be helpful):

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, 
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, ComObj, ComCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  word, doc : Variant;

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
    word.Visible := true;
    doc := word.Documents.Add();
    word.Selection.Font.Name := ('Arial');
    doc.Range.Text := 'The answer is 42.';
    //doc.Save;
  except
    ShowMessage('Microsoft Word couldn''t start');
  end;
end;
```

Can anybody tell me why I do not get any function or property proposals after typing "word." or "doc." and how I can fix that?

Thanks in advance,

Lea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use OLE Automation through the `CreateOleObject` function, Delphi have no data about object methods or properties so it could not invoke code completion. When your code compiles it simply creates `IDispatch` interface invoke calls, so technically you could write any nonexistent method name (for example `doc.SomeSillyNonExistentFunction`) and it will be successfully compiled and fail only at runtime. This is called the *late binding* - function existence and parameters check is performed at runtime instead of compile time. To get access to type data you have to import office type library, or use Delphi office automation `VCL` components, which is pretty much the same.

**Upd:**
To install office VCL components use menu `Components->Install package` and enable package `Microsoft Office sample Automation server Wrapper components`. It will add a new tab in the component palette. If there is no such package (I have XE1 and could not check) use menu `Components->Import component`, select `Import a Type Library` option and then locate Office Word/Excel/etc type library in the list.

Comment: In theory, it might be possible to write an IDE extension to implement a custom `IOTACodeInsightManager` using the type library information for a given ProgID (parsed from the source code or entered by the user) if it's registered on the system.